# VBScript на windows 10 x64 + createobject

Tags: dll, com, реестр, vbscript

зарегистрировал dll в сиcтеме
код bat файла регистрации:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe QueryObjects.dll /register
gacutil.exe -u QueryObjects
tlbexp.exe QueryObjects.dll
gacutil.exe -i QueryObjects.dll
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe QueryObjects.dll /tlb /codebase
```

пытаюсь:

> createobject("QueryObjects.ServerInfo")

выдает ошибку: "Невозможно создание объекта контейнером ActiveX"
код ошибки: 800a01ad

на файл доступы дал все для всех
в реестре dll зарегистрирована

компоненты С++ установил все что мог

больше не знаю что пробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оказалось всё проше

dll заточена под 32-разрядную систему

так я использовал это для classic ASP, нужно было просто разрешить 32-разрядные приложения для пула приложений